# how to publish an App in Chrome Web Store for a specific domain?

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

Im developing an App Engine project for a customer, I want that this project can be installed as an App from the Chrome Web Store, for a specific domain (not mine).

I have enabled the Marketplace SDK and API in my project, and tried to upload the ZIP, but I only can select my domain if I want set the App as private.

I have tried to upload the ZIP with one account from that domain, but when I'm going to publish the App the web gives me an error saying that I dont have permissions to publish because I'm not the owner of the console API Id (because the project stills in my main account, another domain).

Its possible publish the App as private to another domain, that is not the same domain where the App Engine project is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to publish it as a private app then choose only a certain people to share it. It's the only way.
The instructions for publish a private Chrome app for a specific users is found in [Publish a private Chrome app](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en)

> Users from the same Chrome domain will see their organization's
>   private apps in a private collection in the Chrome Web Store.
>
> **Administrators can choose which users they want to be able to publish
>   private apps for their organization** by clicking this checkbox in the
>   Admin console under Device management > Chrome management > User
>   settings > Chrome Web Store Permissions.
>
> When you click Allow users to publish private apps that are restricted
>   to your domain on Chrome Web Store, an additional setting will appear
>   to Allow users to skip verification for websites not owned. This
>   second setting allows users to create bookmark apps pointing to
>   websites that they aren’t the webmaster for.
>
> How to publish private Chrome web apps Publishing a private app is
>   very similar to publishing a public app to the Chrome Web Store. The
>   only difference is there's an additional step of restricting access to
>   the app to your domain:
>
> 1. Sign in to the Chrome developer dashboard.
> 2. Accept the Terms of Service.
> 3. Add a new item and upload your app as a zip file.
> 4. Set the promotional image you want to use, and the category, and language for the app.
> 5. Select Private and Everyone at .
>
> The app is now published to the Chrome Web Store. If you have
>   restricted the visibility of the app to your domain, only users in
>   your organization signed in to their G Suite accounts will be able to
>   see the app

Comment: Where is the "Admin console under Device management"?  I'm not seeing that in the developer dashboard anywhere

Comment: The answer is correct, but the settings have moved slightly to "Device Management >Chrome > Apps & Extensions". You're looking for 'Chrome Web Store Permissions'  Allow users to publish private apps that are restricted to your domain on Chrome Web Store.    For the previous person asking, it's the admin.google.com domain settings.